# Cannot access private member in class sf::NonCopyable. Where is the copy? C++

Tags: c++, sfml

**Using SFML 2.1**

I decided to make an object that contains my audio files. However, when I run my test, I get the following error:

error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'

I looked up some information about this error on the SFML website and it states that I am not able to copy an object that inherits sf::NonCopyable (I think). These objects are probably sf::Sound and sf::Music as I am about to show. The real question is: where is this copy made and how do I fix it?

**Audio class**

```
struct Audio {
    std::map<std::string, sf::Sound> sounds;
    std::map<std::string, sf::Music> musics;

    Audio() : sounds(),
        musics(){}


    void addSound(sf::Sound& s, sf::SoundBuffer& sb, std::string key){
        s.setBuffer(sb);
        sounds.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Sound>(key, s));
    }
    void addSound(sf::Sound& s, std::string key){
        sounds.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Sound>(key, s));
    }
    void addMusic(sf::Music& m, std::string key){
        musics.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Music>(key, m));
    }
    sf::Sound& getSound(std::string key){
        return sounds[key];
    }
    sf::Music& getMusic(std::string key){
        return musics[key];
    }
};
```

**Load Sounds method**

```
void loadSounds(Audio& audio){
    sf::Music backgroundMusic;
    sf::Sound eating;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_eating;
    sf::Sound moving;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_moving;
    sf::Sound losing;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_losing;
    sf::Sound begin;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_begin;

    if (!backgroundMusic.openFromFile("backgroundmusic.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"backgroundmusic.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_eating.loadFromFile("eatingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"eatingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_moving.loadFromFile("movingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"movingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_losing.loadFromFile("losingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"losingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_begin.loadFromFile("beginsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"beginsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;

    eating.setBuffer(sb_eating);
    moving.setBuffer(sb_moving);
    losing.setBuffer(sb_losing);
    begin.setBuffer(sb_begin);

    audio.addMusic(backgroundMusic, std::string("backgroundMusic"));
    audio.addSound(eating, std::string("eating"));
    audio.addSound(moving, std::string("moving"));
    audio.addSound(losing, std::string("losing"));
    audio.addSound(begin, std::string("begin"));
}
```

**Main Method**

```
int main(){
    /*Initialize the objects*/
    Snake snake = Snake();
    Audio& audios = Audio();
    sf::Text textCount;
    Apple apple(0, 0);
    apple.locateApple();
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "SFML Application" );
    /*Load the audio*/
    loadSounds(audios);

    audios.getMusic("backgroundMusic").setVolume(10);
    audios.getMusic("backgroundMusic").setLoop(true);
    audios.getMusic("backgroundMusic").setVolume(25);


    /*Load the font*/
    sf::Font font;
    if (!(font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")))
        std::cout << "Error loading fonts" << std::endl;
    /*Create the text*/
    textCount.setFont(font);
    textCount.setString(std::string("points: ") + std::to_string(points));
    textCount.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    textCount.setCharacterSize(20);
    textCount.setPosition(windowWidth / 2 - (textCount.getString().getSize()*(textCount.getCharacterSize() / 5)), textCount.getCharacterSize() - 5);
    textCount.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

    window.draw(textCount);

    /*Set Framerate fps*/
    window.setFramerateLimit(10);

    /*MAIN GAME LOOP*/
    counterTick = 1;

    audios.getSound("begin").play();
    audios.getMusic("backgroundMusic").play();
    while (inGame)
    {
        std::string counter = std::to_string(counterTick);
        std::cout << "Tick: " + counter << std::endl;

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape)) break;
        /*Call Updates*/
        snake.input();
        snake.checkReals();
        snake.moveUpdate();
        audios.getSound("moving").play();

        /*Call Collisions*/
        std::cout << "     Outside Collision Loop " << std::endl;
        checkApple(snake, apple, audios.getSound("eating"));
        checkBoundary(snake);

        /*Call Draw*/
        std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapearray = snake.draw();
        for (int i = shapearray.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            window.draw(shapearray[i]);
        }
        window.draw(textCount);
        window.draw(apple.draw());
        window.display();

        counterTick++;

    }
    audios.getSound("losing").play();
    audios.getMusic("backgroundMusic").stop();
    std::system("PAUSE");//bad practice, debuggin purposes
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::pair` makes a copy, and then inserting it into the map creates another. Perhaps you want to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: Are you using C++ 11? You might be able to use the new move syntax - basically changing your addSound, addMusic etc functions to take Sound&& etc.

Comment: @Bash Music seems to be the only non-copyable object involved here (since it contains a `sf::Thread`). You're probably going to have to use a pointer to `sf::Music`. Since the SFML guys did not implement a move-constructor it's pretty much your only choice. Oh and the copy was made in this line `musics.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Music>(key, m));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments already mentioned, `sf::Music` can't be copied. Your best bet is to probably just wrap it inside a `std::unique_ptr` since you don't need to share ownership.

Since you said in earlier Questions that you are doing this for school I'm going to show you how to do this in general with C++11

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

//non copyable and non movable like sf::Music
struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() {};
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &&other) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &other) = delete;
    void randomFunc(){}
};

struct MapHolder
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<NonCopyable>> container;

    void addElement(const std::string &key, std::unique_ptr<NonCopyable> value)
    {
        //std::move is necessary here, compiler error without it, since
        //unique_ptr<T> is non-copyable but can be moved just fine
        container.insert({key , std::move(value)});
    }

    NonCopyable &get(const std::string &key)
    {
        //using container[key] will create a new NonCopyable if none is found
        //this will however throw an exception if key is not in the map
        return *container.at(key);  
    }

    //probably not necessary in this case but this is so that you can get a 
    //const NonCopyable elements from a "const MapHolder", without this, 
    //calling ".get" on a "const MapHolder" would be an error
    const NonCopyable &get(const std::string &key) const
    {
        return *container.at(key);
    }

};


int main()
{
    MapHolder holder;

    auto myInstance = std::make_unique<NonCopyable>();
    //if make_unique is not supported on your compiler use this:
    //auto myInstance = std::unique_ptr<NonCopyable>(new NonCopyable());

    //this is how you access members of NonCopyable
    myInstance->randomFunc();

    //again, the move here is necessary, since std::unique_ptr is non-copyable
    //after this line "myInstance" is invalid
    holder.addElement("test", std::move(myInstance));

    //doing this is illegal now, since myInstance is now moved
    //it should be noted that std::move was only a cast, the actual moving
    //happened because "addElement" took the unique_ptr by value and
    //thereby transferred the ownership during construction of its local parameter
    //myInstance->randomFunc();

    //this is ok
    holder.get("test").randomFunc();

    //this is fine too
    NonCopyable &local_ref = holder.get("test");
    local_ref.randomFunc();  

    return(0);
}
```